# Sorting values in r to make stacked boxplots

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing the ages and sex of people with heart disease. From this, I would like to take 2 vectors, each containing all the ages for one of the sexes. However, I can't figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated! The data looks like this:

```
          age sex 
   1      63   1 
   2      37   1 
   3      41   0 
   4      56   1 
   5      51   0
```

I would want my two vectors to be (63, 37, 56) and (41, 51).

I've tried doing `males <- data$sex==1` `females <- data$sex==1` but this just gives me 2 vectors full of true or false and not the lines of data containing the sex and age. I am unsure what other options I have to try or how to word a google search for them.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're after since the title of the question doesn't seem to relate with the question itself. Solutions for both:

```
df <- data.frame(
  age = c(63, 37, 41, 56, 51)
  ,sex = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)

df[df$sex == 1,] # gives you data frame for males, assuming sex == 1 denotes males
```

You don't have to sort data for boxplot. You could simply do this:

```
boxplot(age ~ sex, data = df)
```